# Looking for a Adobe Illustrator to Sketch workflow solution

Tags: adobe-illustrator, sketch-app, interface-design

Does anybody have a Sketch to Illustrator conversion workflow? Reason I am asking is because at the place I am working at a lot of our documentation is done in Illustrator and I have been asked to deliver spec material for the pattern library there in Illustrator format (ai and pdf). I don't want to do that.

I have a technique where I have key commands set up to convert single lines of text back to blocks and another key command for releasing clipping paths. It's a bit more cleanup than I would like to do. Anybody have something better?

This is the script I am using to merge lines of text: http://ajarproductions.com/blog/2008/11/23/merge-text-extension-for-illustrator/

What I have tried:
Copy from Illustrator to Sketch
Save as pdf import to Sketch

The issue with this is that text blocks break apart. Objects like buttons come into illustrator with many clipping paths which make cleaning up a mission

Comment: Have you tried saving in in .EPS and opening it in sketch?

Comment: You might wanna checkout our Illustrator to Sketch converter: https://xd2sketch.com/converter/ai-to-sketch it converts all elements as is, so you don't have to fix any import issues afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Probably SVG is the best format to pass files between Illustrator and SketchApp.

- Sketch - Export ARTBOARD in SVG
- Illustrator - Open, select all, ungroup (couple of times)
- Illustrator - Clean a bit
- Illustrator - Export/Save as .AI

[image: Export to SVG]

Comment: I've tried this. Problem is if you have something like a text field with a stroke those get broken up and text blocks get converted to single lines of text. So clean up almost means rebuild unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can open .ai files with adobe xd. It is free to use. My workflow:

1. Import .ai File in adobe xd
2. Select my needed layers and copy
3. Paste into Sketch
4. Be happy and work with sketch ;)